# Problem with MousePosition after rotating a graphic

Tags: matrix, rotation, dynamic

I've been doing a dynamic matrix plot using [`MousePosition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MousePosition.html) but I need to rotate the plot 45°. but when I do that the [`MousePosition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MousePosition.html) lose coordinates.

Any idea of how to do the rotation keeping [`MousePosition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MousePosition.html) working?.

This is the code I´ve been using:

```
rowNumber[rowdim_] := 
  If[# === None, #, 
    If[MatchQ[#, _?(1 <= # <= rowdim &)], #, None] &[
          1 + rowdim - Last@Ceiling[#]]] &@MousePosition["Graphics"];
colNumber[coldim_] := 
  If[# === None, #, 
   If[MatchQ[#, _?(1 <= # <= coldim &)], #, None] &[
          First@Ceiling[#]]] &@MousePosition["Graphics"];

DynamicModule[{x = {}}, EventHandler[
  Dynamic@MatrixPlot[
     SparseArray[
     Append[Map[# -> If[EvenQ@Count[x, #], 1, 0] &, x], {i_, j_} ->       
       1], {7, 7}],
  Mesh -> All],
 {"MouseClicked" :> 
    (x = 
       DeleteCases[
         Append[x, {rowNumber[7],colNumber[7]}], 
         {a_, b_} /; a == None || b == None])}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Your question appears to be incomplete. I see no code that does any rotating of the plot.

Comment: The OPs code draws a grid that you can click on. Each place you click, the color changes. But now you Rotate the image by 45 degrees (wrap around the MatrixPlot, for instance)... if you do so, then when you click on the boxes, the mouse is offset from location where the color changes.

Comment: Yes, i put the version without rotate[,45°].   Yeah i know it is an offset, but the problem is that there are parts of the rotated matrix plot that MousePosition don't recognize and give {None,None} so i can't fix that with just by finding the offset and aplying that offset to coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply `RotationTransform[θ]` to the graphics primitives produced by `MatrixPlot` and `RotationTransform[-θ]` to the`MousePosition` coordinates:

```
θ = π/4;
rowNumber[rowdim_] := If[# === None, #, If[MatchQ[#, _?(1 <= # <= rowdim &)], #, None] &[
      1 + rowdim - Last@Ceiling[RotationTransform[-θ]@#]]] &[MousePosition["Graphics"]];
colNumber[coldim_] := If[# === None, #, If[MatchQ[#, _?(1 <= # <= coldim &)], #, None] &[
      First@Ceiling[RotationTransform[-θ]@#]]] &@ MousePosition["Graphics"];
DynamicModule[{x = {}}, 
 EventHandler[Dynamic@MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, RotationTransform[θ]] &,
     MatrixPlot[SparseArray[Append[Map[# -> If[EvenQ@Count[x, #], 1, 0] &, x], 
      {i_, j_} -> 1], {7, 7}], Mesh -> All, Frame -> False, 
     ImageSize -> 1 -> 50], {1}], 
  {"MouseClicked" :> (x = DeleteCases[Append[x, {rowNumber[7], colNumber[7]}], {a_, b_} /; 
     a == None || b == None])}]]
```

[image]

If you need the frame and frame ticks, you can overlay a rotated empty plot with the same image size setting:

```
DynamicModule[{x = {}}, EventHandler[Dynamic@Overlay[{Rotate[#, θ] &@
    MatrixPlot[ConstantArray[0, {7, 7}], ImageSize -> 1 -> 50], 
   MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, RotationTransform[θ]] &, 
    MatrixPlot[SparseArray[Append[Map[# -> If[EvenQ@Count[x, #], 1, 0] &, x], 
       {i_, j_} -> 1], {7, 7}], Mesh -> All, Frame -> False, ImageSize -> 1 -> 50], {1}]}, 
    All, 2, Alignment -> Center], 
    {"MouseClicked" :> (x = DeleteCases[Append[x, {rowNumber[7], colNumber[7]}], 
      {a_, b_} /; a == None || b == None])}]]
```

[image]

Use `θ = π/6` to get

[image]